# Add lines to file by using array commands with php

Tags: php, html, arrays, file, preg-replace

I'm trying to make a php script that adds an IP to a firewall. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to insert `$ip` into the 12th line of the data on `iptables` then write it to `iptables2`. Is there another way I should be doing this or is this the easiest?

```
<?php
//Firewall string
$ip = "-A INPUT -s " . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . " -j ACCEPT" . "\n";

//Turn file into array
$file = file('iptables');

//Insert string into array
$res = array_splice($file, 12, 0, $ip);

//Write to another file
file_put_contents("iptables2", $res);

//Display new file
$iptables2 = file("iptables2");
echo "<ul>";
foreach($iptables2 as $s => $r) {
    echo "<li>" . $s . "=>" . $r . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

`iptables` looks like this:

```
*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
# Port 5060
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Remote Operators
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Remote Phones
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Port 3306 - Mysql from Known Sources
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
# Reject The Rest
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -j REJECT
COMMIT
```

Line 12 is `# Remote Phones`, and I want to get `-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT` inserted after line 12.

Comment: just make sure that you're running this script only once :)

Comment: But what if I wanted to use it multiple times and add multiple entries after `# Remote Phones` ?

Comment: i think that there's no problem, just try to not have entries's duplicates in your IP table, your code seems clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using a regex to find and replace `# Remote Operators`. So you dont have to know the line where the string appears.

```
$ipTables= '*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
# Port 5060
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Remote Operators
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Remote Phones
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
# Port 3306 - Mysql from Known Sources
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
# Reject The Rest
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -j REJECT
COMMIT';

$search = '# Remote Operators';
$ip = '-A INPUT -s YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY -j ACCEPT';

echo preg_replace('/^' . $search . '.*/m', "$search\n$ip", $ipTables);
```

You can see a live example at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a0d6dddd228ef79d441b015a58f210d054cf04e

In your case you would read the contents of `$ipTables` from a file.

Comment: Will this work multiple times or with this one work once? In other words, If I add `XXX.YYY.XXX.YYY` after `# Remote Phones` will I be able to add in additional IPs after `# Remote Phones` again?

Comment: Yes, this will add a new line every time you use the code. Be aware that this may produce duplicate.